# Could you help me understand the notation in my professor's lectures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, notation

My lecturer in functional analysis constantly write the notation such as $\lambda(dy)$ in integral for a measure $\lambda$ .For example for a operator $$ Tf:=\int exp(x-y)^2f(y)\lambda(dy)$$

I am a little confused with this notation as I only came across the notation like $$ \int exp(x-y)^2f(y)d\lambda(y) $$ before in measure theory.I guess two notations are the same .

Could anyone explains the first notation?

Thanks.

Comment: It is probably related to Radon Nikodym theorem, which says roughly speaking that a measure $\lambda$ corresponds to a function $g$ such that $\int f d\lambda = \int fg dx$

Comment: He constantly writes something you do not understand and you did not ask him? If instead he had started to lecture in Rumanian, would you have told him you did not understand him?

Comment: Thanks for your criticism. I will try to change my personality but I am not very used to asking lecturers for help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the notations $\lambda(dy)$ and $d\lambda(y)$ are equivalent.  They both mean to integrate the expression as a function of $y$ with respect to the measure $\lambda$.